# "usage:\n\tll '(a+a)'" meaning in ll1 parser program

Tags: cpu-usage

I am unable to understand what is the role of "usage:\n\tll '(a+a)'" in the code. What is its function?? I am using g++ compiler to compile the code. If more than 2 arguments are passed in command prompt then problem occurs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stack>

enum Symbols {

    TS_L_PARENS,    
    TS_R_PARENS,    
    TS_A,       
    TS_PLUS,    
    TS_EOS,     
    TS_INVALID, 
    NTS_S,      
    NTS_F   
};
enum Symbols lexer(char c)
{
switch(c)
{
case '(':  return TS_L_PARENS;
case ')':  return TS_R_PARENS;
case 'a':  return TS_A;
case '+':  return TS_PLUS;
case '\0': return TS_EOS; 
default:   return TS_INVALID;
}
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
using namespace std;
if (argc < 2)
{
cout << **"usage:\n\tll '(a+a)'"** << endl;
return 0;
}
map< enum Symbols, map<enum Symbols, int> > table; 
stack<enum Symbols> ss; // symbol stack
char *p;    // input buffer
ss.push(TS_EOS);    // terminal, $
ss.push(NTS_S);     // non-terminal, S
p = &argv[1][0];
table[NTS_S][TS_L_PARENS] = 2;
table[NTS_S][TS_A] = 1;
table[NTS_F][TS_A] = 3;
while(ss.size() > 0)
{
if(lexer(*p) == ss.top())
{
cout << "Matched symbols: " << lexer(*p) << endl;
p++;
ss.pop();
}
else
{
cout << "Rule " << table[ss.top()][lexer(*p)] << endl;
switch(table[ss.top()][lexer(*p)])
{
case 1: // 1. S → F
ss.pop();
ss.push(NTS_F); // F
break;
case 2: // 2. S → ( S + F )
ss.pop();
ss.push(TS_R_PARENS);   // )
ss.push(NTS_F);     // F
ss.push(TS_PLUS);   // +
ss.push(NTS_S);     // S
ss.push(TS_L_PARENS);   // (
break;
case 3: // 3. F → a
ss.pop();
ss.push(TS_A);  // a
break;
default:
cout << "parsing table defaulted" << endl;
return 0;
break;
}
}
}
cout << "finished parsing" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is the function, `"usage:\n\tll '(a+a)'"` is a string literal passed to the function.  This bit in your question prints:

```
usage:
    ll '(a+a)'
```